# vb.net - error filling data adapter with dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, dataadapter

below is my code:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT VisitorID, VisitorName, Skill FROM tblVisitor LEFT JOIN tblSkill ON tblVisitor.SkillID = tblSkill.SkillID", myConnection)
   myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
   myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")
   tblView.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
```

then it catch an error as `Incorrect Syntax near".` which it points to `myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")` not the Select command.

Please help.

Comment: Try to check your statement at the sql server to find out what part of your statement is not wright. check If all your columns in the statement exist in db too. The error points to the fill statement because this is the position when your selectCommand will be executed. So the error must be in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior that the exception is thrown on `DataAdapter.Fill` and not on building the SqlCommand. Because `Fill` is the first point where ADO.NET will query your database.

What comes after "Incorrect syntax near"? Because normally the database will give you a hint where to find the error in SQL-Statement.

Your SQl-Statement seems to be correct if your Model is similar to this test-model:

```
declare  @tblVisitor table(
    VisitorID int,
    VisitorName varchar(100),
    SkillID int
)
declare @tblSkill table(
    SkillID int,
    Skill int
)

INSERT INTO @tblVisitor VALUES(1,'Name1',1);
INSERT INTO @tblVisitor VALUES(2,'Name2',2);
INSERT INTO @tblVisitor VALUES(3,'Name3',3);

INSERT INTO @tblSkill VALUES(1,100);
INSERT INTO @tblSkill VALUES(2,200);
INSERT INTO @tblSkill VALUES(3,300);

SELECT VisitorID, VisitorName, Skill
FROM   @tblVisitor tblVisitor LEFT JOIN
       @tblSkill tblSkill ON tblVisitor.SkillID = tblSkill.SkillID
```

The result:

```
VisitorID   VisitorName  Skill
   1          Name1       100
   2          Name2       200
   3          Name3       300
```

Answer (score 0):

have you created instance for your dataset??

refer this

[check this](http://vbnetsample.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-dataset-from-database.html)

Comment: of course, i declared it as a global variable. The problem occurs just when I change my sql statement from `"SELECT * FROM tblVisitor"` to the such above sql statement. The previous one works well